# Visual Studio doesn't run my Python Script / Calling a defined function doesn't work

Tags: python, visual-studio

So I am developing my first little text adventure game in Python.
For every available choice I wanted to define a certain function, so that I can do something like

```
if choice in answer_A:
      option_1()
else:
      option_2()

def option_1():
      print("...")

def option_2():
      print("...")
```

The problem is that Visual Studio detects my defined function, but I am unable to call it properly.[Here is a picture of what my code looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUDat.png)

It should work fine and in IDLE it does, but Visual Studio seems to have a problem with this...

Comment: What's the error that shows up?